# tab control webpart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net. And I want to develop a WebPart, like a tab based control, like task manager, items (e.g. processes, users, etc.) are managed by tab on the top for different categories, and in each category tab, items are organized in list. I need to get information about which tab is selected in my requirement.

Any reference code or document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
[jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: "integrate it with .Net code" -- I mean I need to use C# code at server side to fill dynamic content for each tab.